# How to shift up individual elements within a flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a "footer" element with this block of text on the left and a single image on the right. It looks like this:

[image]

The HTML is formatted as such:

```
            <div className="footer">
                <div id="img-container">
                    <div id="img">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src={image} alt=""></img>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="list-container">
                    <div id="list">
                        <ul>
                           // A bunch of li's 
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

My CSS:

```
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 690px;
}

#img {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 1050px;
}

#list-container {
  z-index: 10000;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#list li  {
    list-style-type: none;
    color:  rgb(253, 0, 0);
    font: 15px Courier;
    padding-bottom:7px;
}
```

My question is, how can I shift up the div with id img? Since it's part of a flexbox, it also affects the list of text on the left if I try anything like margin-top or top, and sometimes it won't move at all. I'm not sure if I need to specify a "position" rule or something.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't reproduce this behaviour, so we can't help. Please include a [MRE] with the relevant code required to recreate the problem so we can hee what might be causing it and be able to help.

Comment: what are the chances that the image you added contains white space? or `padding-top `causing the image to move down. Because I didn't see your problem with the CSS code you provided for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the position to absolute to the #img. In this way, it will be determined by his direct antecessor.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to shift up img so that two containers are top line aligned, you can update style of .footer as following

```
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start; // Update this line
  z-index: 10;
  top: 690px;
```

If you just need a small adjustment you could add padding to img-container

```
#img-container {
  padding-bottom: 10px; // replace 10 with whatever number making it good
}
```